# Running rosjava tutorial examples

Tags: ros, node, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tried usual searches to see if anyone else was seeing this, but when I run:

rosrun rosjava_bootstrap run.py rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.Listener

I get an error that says:

Loading node class: org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.Listener
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Node name not specified.

I noticed that the documentation for rosjava seems a bit out of date (since NodeFactory.newNode no longer takes a default name), so it could be that I need some sort of argument, but I don't know what it is.

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12069/running-rosjava-tutorial-examples/) by [SFurtwangler](https://answers.ros.org/users/1432/sfurtwangler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is now handled by NodeMain.getDefaultNodeName(). It is no longer required to specify "__name:=...".

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1